Website shows Server error 500. Suspect it's SSL releated
My site was working just fine, and then it stopped for reasons I don’t know. I get a Server Error 500. I believe it’s related to SSL, because in most browsers I get that error, but in Brave it goes to http and works fine (as http). My site log lists no errors, and I don’t see any in the apache logs either.
The relevant settings.py:
secure proxy SSL header and secure cookies
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
session expire at browser close
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

wsgi scheme
os.environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https' 
and wsgi.py:
os.environ['HTTPS'] = "on"
and in my apache 000-default_ssl.conf:
SSL section
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mysite.key

and lastly, in the 000-default.conf I have:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]


I could really use some help. Thanks.
I checked the site log, and the apache logs. There's no evidence of errors. I only suspect it's an SSL problem because it oddly works in a Brave browser and not others.

May be it's no SSL error, because if it can't establish the connection, the request will be filtered at SSL layer. Have you checked Apache error log ?
